# Iterating over data from mongoose in node

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have this fiddle that illustrates what I want to do and it works as intended:
https://jsfiddle.net/mbLwsnak/

All it does is loop through an array of objects, and adds a key value pair.

I have this same code in my node app, and it doesn't work. The new pair is not added to the objects, even though the code is practically the same, so I figure it must be the context.

```
Schema.find()
.then(function(currencydata){

    var data = currencydata;

    data.forEach(function(obj){
        obj.thing = "Thing";
    })

    console.log(data);
    mdata.currencydata = data;

})
.then(function(result){
    res.render('index', mdata);
})
```

So the only difference I can think of that matters is that this is all inside an asynchronous function. I even tried putting the log inside a setTimeout in case it was something to do with being async, but no change.

Edit:
currencydata is an array of objects returned by the mongoose schema. It looks like this:

```
[{
  country: 'Canada',
  currency: 'CAD',
  cost: 5.98,
  exchangerate: 1.33,
  value: -10.9
}, {
  country: 'United States',
  currency: 'USD',
  cost: 5.06,
  exchangerate: 1,
  value: 0
}, {
  country: 'India',
  currency: 'INR',
  cost: 170,
  exchangerate: 68.33,
  value: -50.8
}]
```

Comment: I'm no mongoose expert; but isnt the "obj" a mongoose model? Have you tried `.save()` (if the intent is to actually save the "Thing". If save is not intended, use the `.toJSON()` and modify the returned object (which is not a mongoose model).

Comment: I just realized that it sounds like I'm trying to save a new key pair to my MongoDB. I'm not. I'm strictly manipulating the data in the array returned, just like in my fiddle. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use lean() to convert a mongoose document into a plain javascript
  object.
- Then inside the first then() you need to return a promise so that the
  next then() will get the returned value.

Inside the promise object, the **resolve** and **reject** functions, when called, resolve or reject the promise, respectively. [Promise Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

```
Schema.find()
    .lean()
    .then((currencydata, err) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            currencydata.forEach(data => {
                data.thing = 'Thing';
            });
            resolve(currencydata);
        });
    })
    .then((newdata, err) => {
        res.render('index', newdata);
    });
```